# How to update firebase user display name

Tags: reactjs, async-await, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to change the display name after registration, but the reset password name placeholder %DISPLAY_NAME% is still empty.
Am I doing it incorrectly?

```
//firstName is parameter to this thunk 
const auth = getAuth(fireApp);
    try {
        const authUserData = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {displayName: firstName});
 catch (error) {}
```

Comment: From what I understand, updating user details like this doesn't automagically update anything that was *just* fetched upon logging in. I believe you'd need to update the user object you are likely saving in the frontend.

Comment: Thanks, you mean by User.reload() or what?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#userreload

The following example shows basically what I had:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

Comment: Sure, reloading the user may work (*I can't confirm though*), but I meant something more like updating the user object the app cached locally in state to have the user property.